# cpu thread affinity, any standards? [non openMP]

Tags: c, pthreads, cygwin, posix

Is there a standard/procedure in C(99)/posix to pin threads to cores?
In my case, I am using cygwin (pthreads), I am looking for a method equal to "pthread_setaffinity_np" of gcc (which is non portable), And using openMP is not a solution for me.

I have searched for it high and low, but it is beyond me how such a thing is not adopted by any standard yet, I am sure i am missing on something, Can anyone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Did you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472441/pthread-affinity-before-create-threads

Comment: Have you noticed the part in which the examples are using the nonportable "pthread_attr_setaffinity_np"?